# plsql FOR LOOP not stopping

Tags: plsql

I want to add a certain column to all tables which meet a certain criteria e.g. LIKE 'NAME%'. While my code is working - in a way - I get the error message:

> 1430. 00000 -  "column being added already exists in table"

Why is the loop continuing, even if all tables with the specified criteria in my DB are altered (which they are, I checked)?

```
set serverout on
DECLARE
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
    FOR x in (SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name LIKE 'QM_%')
    LOOP
        sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE '||x.TABLE_NAME||' ADD (TEST Integer)';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( sql_stmt ||';') ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
 END;
```

Comment: you query the wrong table (must be a table where each table is present one time, not often .. ALL_TABLES maybe?)

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Check! Write it down, glad to accept it!

Comment: ok, i´ll do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this:

use `ALL_TABLES` instead of the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` table (in `ALL_TABLES` each table is present with a row, in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` multiple times depending on your field count)

```
set serverout on
DECLARE
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
    FOR x in (SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE 'QM_%')
    LOOP
        sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE '||x.TABLE_NAME||' ADD (TEST Integer)';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( sql_stmt ||';') ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
 END;
```

I think, you do not need the `commit` (it´s not a `DML` but a `DDL` statement).